# Is there a way to generate 10 numbers per row?

Tags: arrays, c

I am attempting to printf 10 prime numbers per row in section 'printf("%d ",i);
'. I know I need a for loop somewhere, but I can't seem to figure out where it should be placed. I am thinking it comes before the if statement (if(flag[i] == 1 && i > 40000).

```
#include<stdio.h>

#define SIZE 50000

int main(void){
    int i, mult, count, count2,j;
    
    int flag[SIZE+1];
    
    count = 0;
    count2 = 0;
    //sets up all numbers
    for(i = 1; i <= SIZE; i++)
    {
        flag[i] = 1;
        //printf("%d",flag[i]);
    }
    //step 1: selects the prime number
    for(i = 2; i <= SIZE; ++i){
        if(flag[i] == 1){
            ++count;
            mult = i + i;
            //step 2: filters out numbers multiple of that prime number in step 1
            while(mult <= SIZE){
                flag[mult] = 0;
                mult = mult + i;
            }
        }
    }
    //Now that the non-prime numbers have been filtered, this then prints the number and counts the prime numbers
    for(i =1; i <= SIZE; i++)
    {
        
        if(flag[i] == 1 && i > 40000)
        {
            ++count2;
            printf("%d ",i);
            
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
    printf("There are %d primes. \n", count2);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

40009 40013 40031 40037 40039 40063 40087 40093 40099 40111 40123 40127 40129 40151 40153 40163 40169 40177 40189 40193 40213 40231 40237 40241 40253 40277 40283 40289 40343 40351 40357 40361 40387 40423 40427 40429 40433 40459 40471 40483 40487 40493 40499 40507 40519 40529 40531 40543 40559 40577 40583 40591 40597 40609 40627 40637 40639 40693 40697 40699 40709 40739 40751 40759 40763 40771 40787 40801 40813 40819 40823 40829 40841 40847 40849 40853 40867 40879 40883 40897 40903 40927 40933 40939 40949 40961 40973 40993 41011 41017 41023 41039 41047 41051 41057 41077 41081 41113 41117 41131 41141 41143 41149 41161 41177 41179 41183 41189 41201 41203 41213 41221 41227 41231 41233 41243 41257 41263 41269 41281 41299 41333 41341 41351 41357 41381 41387 41389 41399 41411 41413 41443 41453 41467 41479 41491 41507 41513 41519 41521 41539 41543 41549 41579 41593 41597 41603 41609 41611 41617 41621 41627 41641 41647 41651 41659 41669 41681 41687 41719 41729 41737 41759 41761 41771 41777 41801 41809 41813 41843 41849 41851 41863 41879 41887 41893 41897 41903 41911 41927 41941 41947 41953 41957 41959 41969 41981 41983 41999 42013 42017 42019 42023 42043 42061 42071 42073 42083 42089 42101 42131 42139 42157 42169 42179 42181 42187 42193 42197 42209 42221 42223 42227 42239 42257 42281 42283 42293 42299 42307 42323 42331 42337 42349 42359 42373 42379 42391 42397 42403 42407 42409 42433 42437 42443 42451 42457 42461 42463 42467 42473 42487 42491 42499 42509 42533 42557 42569 42571 42577 42589 42611 42641 42643 42649 42667 42677 42683 42689 42697 42701 42703 42709 42719 42727 42737 42743 42751 42767 42773 42787 42793 42797 42821 42829 42839 42841 42853 42859 42863 42899 42901 42923 42929 42937 42943 42953 42961 42967 42979 42989 43003 43013 43019 43037 43049 43051 43063 43067 43093 43103 43117 43133 43151 43159 43177 43189 43201 43207 43223 43237 43261 43271 43283 43291 43313 43319 43321 43331 43391 43397 43399 43403 43411 43427 43441 43451 43457 43481 43487 43499 43517 43541 43543 43573 43577 43579 43591 43597 43607 43609 43613 43627 43633 43649 43651 43661 43669 43691 43711 43717 43721 43753 43759 43777 43781 43783 43787 43789 43793 43801 43853 43867 43889 43891 43913 43933 43943 43951 43961 43963 43969 43973 43987 43991 43997 44017 44021 44027 44029 44041 44053 44059 44071 44087 44089 44101 44111 44119 44123 44129 44131 44159 44171 44179 44189 44201 44203 44207 44221 44249 44257 44263 44267 44269 44273 44279 44281 44293 44351 44357 44371 44381 44383 44389 44417 44449 44453 44483 44491 44497 44501 44507 44519 44531 44533 44537 44543 44549 44563 44579 44587 44617 44621 44623 44633 44641 44647 44651 44657 44683 44687 44699 44701 44711 44729 44741 44753 44771 44773 44777 44789 44797 44809 44819 44839 44843 44851 44867 44879 44887 44893 44909 44917 44927 44939 44953 44959 44963 44971 44983 44987 45007 45013 45053 45061 45077 45083 45119 45121 45127 45131 45137 45139 45161 45179 45181 45191 45197 45233 45247 45259 45263 45281 45289 45293 45307 45317 45319 45329 45337 45341 45343 45361 45377 45389 45403 45413 45427 45433 45439 45481 45491 45497 45503 45523 45533 45541 45553 45557 45569 45587 45589 45599 45613 45631 45641 45659 45667 45673 45677 45691 45697 45707 45737 45751 45757 45763 45767 45779 45817 45821 45823 45827 45833 45841 45853 45863 45869 45887 45893 45943 45949 45953 45959 45971 45979 45989 46021 46027 46049 46051 46061 46073 46091 46093 46099 46103 46133 46141 46147 46153 46171 46181 46183 46187 46199 46219 46229 46237 46261 46271 46273 46279 46301 46307 46309 46327 46337 46349 46351 46381 46399 46411 46439 46441 46447 46451 46457 46471 46477 46489 46499 46507 46511 46523 46549 46559 46567 46573 46589 46591 46601 46619 46633 46639 46643 46649 46663 46679 46681 46687 46691 46703 46723 46727 46747 46751 46757 46769 46771 46807 46811 46817 46819 46829 46831 46853 46861 46867 46877 46889 46901 46919 46933 46957 46993 46997 47017 47041 47051 47057 47059 47087 47093 47111 47119 47123 47129 47137 47143 47147 47149 47161 47189 47207 47221 47237 47251 47269 47279 47287 47293 47297 47303 47309 47317 47339 47351 47353 47363 47381 47387 47389 47407 47417 47419 47431 47441 47459 47491 47497 47501 47507 47513 47521 47527 47533 47543 47563 47569 47581 47591 47599 47609 47623 47629 47639 47653 47657 47659 47681 47699 47701 47711 47713 47717 47737 47741 47743 47777 47779 47791 47797 47807 47809 47819 47837 47843 47857 47869 47881 47903 47911 47917 47933 47939 47947 47951 47963 47969 47977 47981 48017 48023 48029 48049 48073 48079 48091 48109 48119 48121 48131 48157 48163 48179 48187 48193 48197 48221 48239 48247 48259 48271 48281 48299 48311 48313 48337 48341 48353 48371 48383 48397 48407 48409 48413 48437 48449 48463 48473 48479 48481 48487 48491 48497 48523 48527 48533 48539 48541 48563 48571 48589 48593 48611 48619 48623 48647 48649 48661 48673 48677 48679 48731 48733 48751 48757 48761 48767 48779 48781 48787 48799 48809 48817 48821 48823 48847 48857 48859 48869 48871 48883 48889 48907 48947 48953 48973 48989 48991 49003 49009 49019 49031 49033 49037 49043 49057 49069 49081 49103 49109 49117 49121 49123 49139 49157 49169 49171 49177 49193 49199 49201 49207 49211 49223 49253 49261 49277 49279 49297 49307 49331 49333 49339 49363 49367 49369 49391 49393 49409 49411 49417 49429 49433 49451 49459 49463 49477 49481 49499 49523 49529 49531 49537 49547 49549 49559 49597 49603 49613 49627 49633 49639 49663 49667 49669 49681 49697 49711 49727 49739 49741 49747 49757 49783 49787 49789 49801 49807 49811 49823 49831 49843 49853 49871 49877 49891 49919 49921 49927 49937 49939 49943 49957 49991 49993 49999
There are 930 primes.

Expected Output:

40009 40013 40031 40037 40039 40063 40087 40093 40099 40111

...
There are 930 primes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is this :

```
for(i =1; i <= SIZE; i++)
{
    
    if(flag[i] == 1 && i > 40000)
    {

        ++count2;
        printf("%d ",i);
        if(count2 % 10 == 0){
            printf("\n");   
        }
        
    }
}
```

By adding :

```
if(count2 % 10 == 0){
    printf("\n");   
}
```

You add a newline character after every 10 primes group.